# i can't understand where i made a mistake and i get this result "syntax error at or near"

Tags: postgresql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF2ts.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Y2n.png)

i can't understand where i made a mistake and i get this result "syntax error at or near"
I've tried all types of brackets and I don't know what else to try.
create table urun
(
id integer primary key not null,
ad varchar(15) not null,
stok integer,
katgori varchar(15),
marka varchar(20),
)

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the last comma. ( marka varchar(20))